# Properties of User Control created by other User Control in design time lose property contents when rebuilding

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a Host UserControl which creates bunch of other UserControls at design time. Some Properties of the created userControls need to be stored in the host UserControl. There is no problem before I rebuild the solution. But after rebuilding all properties get lost. How can I make Properties Permanent even after rebuilding?

Comment: WinForms, WebForms or WPF? How are the poperties 'stored in the host UserControl'?  This is not answerable.

Comment: it's winforms... just let me know what you need, so I'll quickly answer...

Comment: Well.. note the page views on this page, you don't get many visitors. You need to present the full details, and the sooner the better. For instance, "UserControl which creates bunch of other UserControls" is not a standard practice, nobody knows how you are doing that.

Comment: The only thing that would work here is a minimal but complete sample.

Comment: will provide @weekend... thx for the answers Henk... much appreciated...